# Parsing /proc/mounts in Java

Tags: java, parsing, encoding

I am trying to parse the results of running `cat /proc/mounts` in a Linux environment.

When mounts contain special characters such as spaces, they are escaped.  An example of this is

`/home/user/media\040/image.dd /media/dd ...`  where the \040 is actually a space.

I am trying to parse this in java but do not want to write a manual parser as I have to believe this is done already and done more robustly than I would.  Is there a class which takes care of decoding this?  I found one or two octal decoders, but they don't work with text and octal intermingled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up using Apache Commons Lang.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava(java.lang.String)

That seems to unescape everything properly.

Comment: Care to share your code?  I'd love to see a good Java library for wrapping/interacting with Linux utilities & command line.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse /proc/mounts using getmntent in C.

You can implement it In Java accoring to rule:

space (\040), tab (\011), newline (\012)  and  back-slash  (\134)

Or none means swap partitions.

man getmntent:

The mntent structure is defined in  as follows:

```
       struct mntent {
           char *mnt_fsname;   /* name of mounted file system */
           char *mnt_dir;      /* file system path prefix */
           char *mnt_type;     /* mount type (see mntent.h) */
           char *mnt_opts;     /* mount options (see mntent.h) */
           int   mnt_freq;     /* dump frequency in days */
           int   mnt_passno;   /* pass number on parallel fsck */
       };

   Since  fields  in  the mtab and fstab files are separated by whitespace, octal escapes are
   used to represent the four characters space (\040), tab (\011), newline (\012)  and  back-
   slash  (\134) in those files when they occur in one of the four strings in a mntent struc-
   ture.  The routines addmntent() and getmntent() will convert from string representation to
   escaped representation and back.
```

Another way: to parse result of "mount" directly. to split them by "on", "type", and so on may be more simple.

Comment: The problem is you could have escaped characters, (legal, yet really stupid names).  So "something\\040something" could be valid.  Also, splitting on key words can be quite dangerous with mounts of that name.  I'm looking for a solution that always works.  I've actually already written a C program that uses getmntent and outputs to a known format, but I was looking to get away from shipping a native tool with the Jar.